# Chrome google cloud messaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I am very new to chrome extension.I want to subscribe to gcm and receive push notifications.Where can I find documents related to there and work on the same?

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) but take into account that GCM is deprecated

Comment: Your oft better using FCM with Chrome Extension as GCM is deprecated. There's a [Firebase Auth w/ Google Sign-In in Chrome Extension](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension) demo to get you started.